# Reuse thread for different action

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

What is the proper way of reusing threads in .net? I know the threadpool does it but I'm not sure how. I already have server code with a lot (100+) threads working just fine but at the moment I have a new scenario where i need to reuse threads not for the same action but for a different one.

If I have 2 methods, how do I reuse a thread mapped to method one and map it to run method 2 instead?

Pseudo code:

```
 var thread = new Thread(method1);
 do work with thread here
 done, now how do i reuse the thread but tell it which method to run without creating a new one?
```

Note that I'm not looking for suggestions about how to accomplish this without using threads, I do need to use threads directly, neither the threadpool nor the task systems fits my use case at all (not willing to debate it here). I'm just not sure about how to cleanly recycle a thread and map it to another function for a new run

Comment: This is what Tasks are for. Use a Task not a  Thread directly

Comment: @MikeSW A `Task` is an abstraction for a unit of work that completes asynchronously.  `Thread` is a mechanism for creating a thread to do work asynchronously.  `Task` does have some built in mechanisms for using threads to do work where the mechanism is hidden from you, but they are not always sufficient.  In some situations you need to create additional tools that use the underlying mechanisms differently.  In this case, he may need to create an abstraction that uses a `Thread` to create `Tasks`.  That doesn't mean it's wrong to use `Thread` directly.

Comment: @MikeSW If you had read the question until the end you'd understand your comment is pointless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply write a method that does one unit of work, and then when finished, goes and does another.  As far as `Thread` as concerned, it's just running it's one delegate, like it always does.  That the delegate run happens to do two (or more, as it can keep finding work to do) logically separate operations in your program is something it doesn't know (or care) about.

A common situation, which is more or less what the thread pool does, is to have a queue of "things to do" and threads that just have a loop that, in the body of the loop, pulls an item from the queue and processes it.  (Just make sure to properly synchronize the data shared between threads here.)

Comment: Along with the task queue approach, you can apply the visitor pattern to your tasks.  So the thread just gets the next task and calls its "DoWork" method.  The thread doesn't care what the task is, it just knows it's supposed to execute it.

Comment: That would only work if my scenario was "do method 1, then 2" this was a sample, here i do one unit of work, then the thread is no longer used, and when another unit of work comes i need to be able to recycle a thread for it.

Comment: So basically i'd have to Schedule not the end code but my own dispatcher code on the thread and have that execute the current task? Sounds overly complicated but i guess i should've expected that, i was hoping i had missed a thread.delegate -= currentmethod += newmethod kind of functionality but i guess i'll have to do that myself

Comment: @RonanThibaudau As I said, none of that it built out for you, but it's certainly something that you can build out for yourself.  As I mentioned, a synchronized queue of delegates is a primitive version that'll do most of that, but it'd be a pretty bare bones solution.

Comment: @JamesR. You don't need the visitor pattern at all, just delegates (or if you want, an interface with one method).  There's no need for virtual dispatch on the arguments passed, as there need be no arguments passed.

Comment: @Servy, you are correct. That was a bad choice of words on my part. That's really what I meant, just a simple interface.